# During update for package nss/lib32-nss results in "File conflict found nss"

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

During updating on a Arch distro the process is indicating there are conflicting files

`File conflict found nss (/usr/lib/p11-kit-trust.so), lib32-nss (/usr/lib32/p11-kit-trust.so): conflicting files`

Searching the file system I did find these two files

```
[user@Arch ~]$ sudo find / -path /mnt -prune -o -name p11-kit-trust.so -exec file {} \;

/usr/lib32/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c375005cabe8daef2a34a4b67fc2187285e6b3a0, stripped
/usr/lib32/p11-kit-trust.so: symbolic link to libnssckbi.so
/usr/lib/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=eb61c425c55ea05db04ce5bb103604861d3ea27d, stripped
/usr/lib/p11-kit-trust.so: symbolic link to libnssckbi.so
```

After a bit of google-fu, I found a pacman command to determine which package these belong to.  The result of that command is

```
[user@Arch~]$ sudo pacman -Qo /usr/lib32/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
/usr/lib32/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so is owned by lib32-p11-kit 0.23.20-4

[user@Arch ~]$ sudo pacman -Qo /usr/lib/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
/usr/lib/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so is owned by libp11-kit 0.23.20-4
```

I have tried updating one at a time, but that doesn't help.  I am not sure how to resolve this problem.  Any suggestions or ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using and upgrading the Arch Linux implies you keep tracking of upstream sources news.

For this case in particular you find the correct info [here](https://www.archlinux.org/news/nss3511-1-and-lib32-nss3511-1-updates-require-manual-intervention/).

Comment: No, I didn't know about this page before.  I have only started using Arch about two weeks ago.  I will bookmark this page and keep an eye on it.  Thanks

Comment: @lordhog, I **highly** recommend subscribing to [the arch announcements mailing list](https://lists.archlinux.org/listinfo/arch-announce). It's reserved for important news, or changes which require manual intervention (like the above). Never get caught by surprise again!

Comment: @J.M.Janzen, yes, I most certainly will.  Also, during that particular update process it broke the nVidia drivers some how and the system wouldn't bring up the KDE login screen.  It is a good thing I had another device to search.  I had removed/reinstalled the nVidia drivers, was able to post this question, and found out about other consoles using the ctrl/alt and Fx keys to which I could remove/reinstall the nVidia drivers.  Still so much to learn